# ensuring full menu of web page visible on screens of various dimensions

Tags: css, html, size, height

I am new to coding web pages and have run into a bit of difficulty on having the full vertical menu appear on some screens. The menu is designed to remain fixed while the content may be scrolled and this causes a difficulty on devices with low vertical resolutions: they cannot scroll to view all available menu options. What is a reasonable approach to this problem? Some minimal code is presented below (with an increased number of menu options) to illustrate the problem.

Any additional comments on possible improvements would be most welcome. The intention is for this web page to be usable on multiple devices (desktops, tablets, telephones etc.).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background: #c0c0c0;
                color: #000000;
                font-size: 15px;
                line-height: 1.5;
                text-align: justify;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
            }
            h2 {
                margin: 0;
            }
            a:link {
                color: #cb4c2f;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:visited {
                color: #cb4c2f;
            }
            a:active, a:hover {
                color: #b60a00;
            }
            #line_1 {
                size: 500px;
                border-top: 1px solid #000000;
            }
            #line_2 {
                size: 500px;
                border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
            }
            .button_1 {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;          
                background-color: #c0c0c0;
                border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
                display: inline-block;
                color: #000000;
                font-size: 10px;
                text-align: left;
                white-space: normal;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 10px 10px;
                text-decoration: none;        
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #c0c0c0;        
            }
            .button_1:hover {
                color: #c0c0c0;
                background-color: #000000;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
            }
            .button_1:active {
                position: relative;
                top: 0px;
                background-color: #c0c0c0;
                border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
                color: #000000;
            }
            #wrap_1 {
                width: 600px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background: #5c5c5c;
            }
            #header_1 {
                padding: 5px 10px;
                background: #dddddd;
                border-top: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
            }
            #main_1 {
                float: right;
                width: 450px;
                padding: 10px;
                background: #dddddd;
                min-height: 744px; 
            }
            #sidebar_1 {
                position: fixed;
                float: left;
                width: 130px;
                padding: 0px;
                background: #5c5c5c;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #footer_1 {
                clear: both;
                padding: 5px 10px;
                background: #dddddd;
                border-top: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrap_1">
        <div id="header_1"><h1>TITLE</h1></div>
        <div id="main_1">
            content
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar_1">
            <br>
            <input value="HOME" onclick="location.href='index.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <input value="RESOURCES" onclick="location.href='resources.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <input value="LABORATORY NOTEBOOK" onclick="location.href='laboratory_notebook.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <input value="WEBLOG" onclick="location.href='weblog.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <input value="PUBLICATIONS" onclick="location.href='publications.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <input value="LINKS" onclick="location.href='links.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <input value="ANOTHER LINK" onclick="location.href='links.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <input value="ANOTHER LINK" onclick="location.href='links.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <input value="ANOTHER LINK" onclick="location.href='links.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
            <hr class="line_2" border=0 size=0>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_1">
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like optimarcusprime said, you want your page to respond to the client's viewport size. This is called responsive web design. Just wanted to give a more concrete answer.

In your case, you'll want to add a media query to your css. Media queries help you limit the application of CSS rules to when the specified conditions apply. In your case, you could change the sidebar_1's `position` to `relative` when the screen is below a certain height. Put this declaration at the end of your CSS:

```
@media (max-height: 320px) {
    #sidebar_1 {
        position: relative;   
    }
}
```

So, any viewport (the size of the client's viewing area) that is 320px and below will have a menu that is positioned relatively (you can change 320px to any height you want). That way, it will scroll down when the user does.

Here is a jsfiddle with the change: http://jsfiddle.net/yJA4h/1/.

Here is a link to the MDN docs on media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries.

-- Additional Comments --

Since you asked for additional comments, I thought I'd add them here below the main answer. These are mostly just general web development best practices:

1. These days, developers mostly avoid inline JavaScript. So, step 1, you can change the `<input>` elements to simple `<a>` tags with href attributes. An href attribute tells the browser where to go when that element is clicked.

This from your markup

```
<input value="HOME" onclick="location.href='index.html';" type="button" class="button_1">
```

would become

```
<a href="index.html" class="button_1">HOME</a>
```

It provides the same functionality with fewer keystrokes!

1. Web developers are now also moving away from HTML markup that affects the design of a page. Under that philosophy, most of the design action happens in your CSS style declarations. To convert your markup to this philosophy, you could start by removing the `<br>` elements. For example, all of your `<input>` tags (or `<a>` tags if you followed the advice in #1) share class (`button_1`) already, you could give them margin-bottom in the CSS.

Where you have

```
.button_1 {
    ...
}
```

above in the style declarations, add

```
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* or some other number */
```

to create space between each element that has the class `.button_1`.

One of the benefits of these changes is maintainability. It's possible that you could decide you don't want space between the buttons or you want more space. Right now, you'd have to change around 9 lines of your HTML. If you go the CSS route, it's just one spot that needs a change.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options available.  Off the top of my head:

- Give the sidebar the following attributes: "height:100%; overflow: scroll;".  This will force the sidebar to never be taller than the parent element, which should be the browser window.  However, this also causes a scroll bar in the sidebar.
- Learn responsive web design.  This is a relatively new field of web development, which utilizes new CSS techniques and JavaScript to manipulate how a page displays based on the size of the browser window, or the device it's on.  This is probably your best bet, since it is becoming/already is a standard for good web development.  Start here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Good luck!